# Hibernate / JPA entity attribute with a UserType not loaded correctly

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, usertype

I'm running Hibernate 4.3.11.Final on Java 7 and JPA

I've created a UserType to marshal / unmarshal a java enum object to the database storing it as a SMALLINT.

The enum is an attribute of an Address object and represents the general area / locality of the Address.

My problem is this:

When I load the Address directly e.g.:

```
Address anAddress = session.get(Address.class, 123L);
```

it loads fine and I can access the AreaEnum e.g.

```
assert anAddress.getArea() != null; // ALL GOOD
```

However, when I access an address through an aggregate relationship from another entity the AreaEnum is not marshalled and returns a `null`, e.g.

```
Person aPerson = session.get(Person.class, 5L);

assert aPerson.getAddress().getArea() != null; // FAILS HERE
```

Other standard attributes (which have simple column definition annotations) are populated fine.

My annotation for the Area attribute is like this:

```
public class Address {
...
   @Type(type = "mls.dao.util.HibernateAreaEnumType")
   @Column(name = "are_id", nullable = false, updatable = true, columnDefinition = "SMALLINT")
   public AreaEnum getArea() {
      return this.area;
   }

   @Override
   public void setArea(AreaEnum _area) {
      this.area = _area;
   }
...
}
```

Here is the HibernateAreaEnumType UserType class:

```
public class HibernateAreaEnumType implements UserType {

   private final Method parseMethod;

   private final Class clazz;

   public HibernateAreaEnumType() {

      clazz  = AreaEnum.class;
      try {
         // this is a static method
         this.parseMethod = clazz.getMethod("parseEnum", Long.class);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("issue with trying get the parse method of this enum class: " + clazz.getSimpleName(), e);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet _rs, String[] _names, SessionImplementor _sessionImplementor, Object _owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

      Object result = null;

      if (!_rs.wasNull()) {
         Long enumId = (long) _rs.getInt(_names[0]);
         try {
            result = this.parseMethod.invoke(null, enumId);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new HibernateException("issue trying to method to parse value to make enum: " + enumId, e);
         }
      }

      return result;
   }

   @Override
   public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement _ps, Object _value, int _index, SessionImplementor _sessionImplementor) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
      try {
         if (null == _value) {
            _ps.setNull(_index, Types.SMALLINT);
         } else {
            _ps.setLong(_index, ((MarshallableIdEnum) _value).getId());
         }
      } catch (ClassCastException e) {
         throw new IllegalStateException(this.getClass().getName() + ", issue: " + _value + " / " + _index, e);
      }
   }


   private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = {Types.SMALLINT};

   public int[] sqlTypes() {
      return SQL_TYPES;
   }


   public Class returnedClass() {
      return this.clazz;
   }

   @Override
   public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
      return value;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isMutable() {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
      return cached;
   }

   @Override
   public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
      return (Serializable) value;
   }

   @Override
   public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
      return original;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
      return x.hashCode();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
      return (x == y) || ((null != x) && (null != y) && x.equals(y));
   }

}
```

The area column in the address table is defined as:

```
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+                            |
| are_id       | smallint(5) unsigned  | YES  | MUL | NULL                                        |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Just to clarify the data is all there in the table.

By stepping through the code it seems that in the HibernateAreaEnumType the `rs.wasNull()` is returning `true` but looking at the actual data returned from the sql select (using p6spy) shows that the area enum information is there.

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I fundamentally did not understand what the ResultSet.wasNull() call indicated.

Namely that it "Reports whether the last column read had a value of SQL NULL."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

And *not* whether there was an empty result set (which is what I previously thought.

By undestanding this I changed the `nullSafeGet` method from:

```
@Override
   public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet _rs, String[] _names, SessionImplementor _sessionImplementor, Object _owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

      Object result = null;

      if (!_rs.wasNull()) {
         Long enumId = (long) _rs.getInt(_names[0]);
         try {
            result = this.parseMethod.invoke(null, enumId);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new HibernateException("issue trying to method to parse value to make enum: " + enumId, e);
         }
      }

      return result;
   }
```

to

```
@Override
   public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet _rs, String[] _names, SessionImplementor _sessionImplementor, Object _owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

      Object result = null;
      Short shortId = StandardBasicTypes.SHORT.nullSafeGet(_rs, _names[0], _sessionImplementor);

      if (shortId != null) {
         log.debug("setting: " + _names[0] + " : " + _rs.wasNull() + " : " + _owner);
         Long enumId = shortId.longValue();
         try {
            result = this.parseMethod.invoke(null, enumId);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new HibernateException("issue trying to method to parse value to make enum: " + enumId, e);
         }
      } else {
         result = null;
      }

      return result;
   }
```

And then it worked.